# Application unable to connect to database on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, github, ef-code-first, appharbor

I have this application which I am developing for learning purpose. I have hosted the application on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/).
It is ASP.NET MVC and EF Code First.
I added the SQL server free add on for db purpose but come what may the db connectivity is failing.

Code is hosted on Github here :- https://github.com/BilalHasanKhan/BusinessFlow

Please advise or point where I am wrong.

By switching custom error off I found the error:

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not
>   contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been
>   added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.

Comment: Dropping a project and saying "it doesn't work" is not a good way to ask questions here. The best I can do is give you a link to my MVC3, EF Code First project, hosted on AppHarbor too, which works just fine: https://bitbucket.org/diegose/shoppinglist

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, I would have not asked the question if I would have been able to resolve myself. I understand that code first definitely works within appharbor but I am doing something silly or missing some point.It would be great if you can tell me the steps you followed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not telling you to resolve it yourself. I'm telling you to come up with specific issues; not a blanket "I can't connect". Most people won't go through the trouble of checking out your project to find out where the problem is. You can check my code, or Appharbor's latest log post on EF migrations (which also includes source code)

Comment: Agreed! but what I was hoping to get as an answer was a pointer to some post / guide about Code First app on appharbor.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the blog post we recently did on [migrations with EF Code First](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/04/24/automatic-migrations-with-entity-framework-4-3). There's also [example code](https://github.com/friism/CodeFirstMigrations) to along with the post.

Comment: 1 thing I noted was when I downloaded the build, I couldn't find the connectionstring section in the web.config? Is that a problem. Sorry for being naive here but I am new to appharbor.

Comment: Hm, that might be it, try adding an empty one. Please get back to us here or on support@appharbor.com with results.

Comment: When I deploy the app the web.config do have a connection string section which is <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="BusinessFlow" connectionString="data source=Bilal-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=BusinessFlow;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>

Comment: infact on further examination I feel that, since mvc 3 has got 2 web.config one in Views folder and one for application, I think in build download I can only see the one in Views folder and not the application one.